# how to submit a form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress 3.3.1 with `twentyten` theme,

i have created a plugin to create a custom form,

i have successfully installed this in wordpress,

my plugin file code is as follows

```
<?php
function guest_event_form()
{ 

if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['action']=='new registration')
{

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("Insert Query...");
}
else
{
?>
<form method="POST" action="" name="guest_registration" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register Me Now"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new registration" />
</form>
<?php
}
}
add_shortcode( 'guest_event_form', 'guest_event_form' );
?>
```

whenever i am submitting this form, i returns to same page with search results,

so i guess the problem whenever i submit this form, wordpress takes this submit action as a search action, and it starts search

how do i overcome this problem??

Comment: got the solution, it is because of i have write id of my input field as "name" `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">`, i have change this to `<input type="text" id="hisname" name="hisname" value="">`, now its working fine, because `name` is wordpress's internal variable

Comment: you should create a answer with this comment, and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Problem is because of following form element's id

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="">
```

`name` is one of the wordpress internal variable

Change it like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="customername" name="customername" value="">
```